# How to write superscript of a tilde variable

Tags: math-mode, accents, superscripts

I tried to write the above variable:
[image]

using the following scripts:

```
\tilde{W}^{j}
```

But, they are not the same, any suggestion to solve this problem.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This looks like `$\overset{\sim}{W}^{j}$`, but it looks awful.  If the `j` is supposed to be superscript to `\tilde{W}` then your input looks a lot better in my opinion.

Comment: Great Thanks for useful answer, PhelypeOleinik :)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage{yhmath}

\begin{document}
First code using \verb|accents| package:
\[\accentset{\sim}{W}^{j}\]
Second code using \verb|yhmath| package:
\[\widetilde{W}^{j}\]

\end{document}
```